# How to empty href queries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to clear my href queries after a click event.
All what I need is if I click my button again it should clear old queries and add new ones to href.

```
click(function() {
   //adds some queries to href
   var a_href = $('.link').attr('href');
   myArray.forEach(function(index){
     a_href = a_href + index;
     $('.link').attr('href', a_href)
   });
});
```

example:-

default status: href="www.example.com/_size-"

old href: href="www.example.com/_size-xs.m.l"

new href should overwrite the old one: href="www.example.com/_size-l.xl.xxl

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: To clear `href`: `$('.link').attr('href', '')`

Comment: Post an example! What does `myArray` containing? How should the output look like? What happen if there is duplicates?

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth adding an example of before and after of what you want the href to appear like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're looking for something like this:

```js
var myArray = ["xs.m.l", "l.xl.xxl"];
var currentIndex = 0;
$('#btn').click(function() {
   var a_href = $('.link').attr('href');
   a_href = a_href.replace(/(size\-)(.*)$/,"$1"); // remove previous "query"
   a_href = a_href + myArray[currentIndex % myArray.length]; // add the new "query"
   $('.link').attr('href', a_href);
   $('.link').text(a_href)
   currentIndex++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Change Link</button><a class="link" href="www.example.com/_size-">www.example.com/_size-</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help?

```
<a href="#first" class="my_link">Click Me!</a>

<script>   
    $('.my_link').click(function (e) 
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).attr('href', '#another_link');
    });    
</script>
```